# how to split a number in javascript Linux Firefox getting incorrect value, windows show the correct value

Tags: javascript, split

how can I split a number into sub digits. I have a  number `20:55` n need to split in to two parts as `20` and `55`.

```
var mynumber = 20:55;
var split = mynumber.toString();
document.write("Hour : " +  split[0]);
document.write("Minutes : " +  split[1]);
```

but am getting wrong value after toString() function call.

EDIT: 1  This is what I want. This is working fine but only works with windows. In linux Firefox am not getting the correct value in function .. something like `12.200000000000000001` instead of `12.25`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myarray = new Array();
myarray =   [[12.25, 1],[13.25,1]];
//alert(myarray[0][0]);
func(myarray[0][0]) ;
function func(n) {
    var split = n.split(".");
    document.writeln("Number  : " +  n); // Number  : 12.25
    document.writeln("Hour : " +  split[0]); // Hour : 12
    document.writeln("Minutes : " +  split[1]); // Minutes : 25
}
</script>
```

Comment: What does `mynumber` really is ?. The expression `20:55` without quotes, is not syntactically valid.

Comment: can you add where did you get `20:55;` because `var mynumber = 20:55;` itself is an error already... `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Comment: @Reigel, Maybe it works for him?:)

Answer (score 1):

Use **split()** function

```
var number_array=mynumber.split(":")
```

On your example

```
var mynumber = "20:55";
var split = mynumber.split(":");
document.write("Hour : " +  split[0]);
document.write("Minutes : " +  split[1]);
```

More on this

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: But mynumber is not a string, its came from an array.. that is why I tried to convert that into string for splitting.

Comment: Then show us how do you get your number 20:55? (It's not a number really) I'm not sure how do you get it, but you can try mynumber.toString().split(":")

Answer (score 1):

You are using `split()`, a string function, on a number. Use this:

```
    var split = n.toString().split(".");
```

Works perfectly on Firefox 3.6.3 (and Opera 10.60, and Chromium 5), Ubuntu Linux 10.04.

Comment: @hgulyan: see the question, second code block, under "This is what I want" - that one is using `.`

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`split`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/split) function

```
var numSplit = mynumber.split(':');
```

Then you can access each value using `numSplit[0]` and `numSplit[1]`